# Gremlin - Choose one item at random

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop

Consider me as 'user' 1. The aim of the query is to get the posts 'posted' by the people I follow and for each of those posts check:

1. Whether it has been liked by me
2. Whether it has been liked by anyone else that I follow and if yes **choose one of those users at random to return**

Sample data:

```
g.addV('user').property('id',1).as('1')
  addV('user').property('id',2).as('2').
  addV('user').property('id',3).as('3').
  addV('user').property('id',4).as('4').
  addV('post').property('postId','post1').as('p1').
  addV('post').property('postId','post2').as('p2').
  addE('follow').from('1').to('2').
  addE('follow').from('1').to('3').
  addE('follow').from('1').to('4').
  addE('posted').from('2').to('p1').
  addE('posted').from('2').to('p2').
  addE('liked').from('1').to('p2').
  addE('liked').from('3').to('p2').
  addE('liked').from('4').to('p2').iterate()
```

Query: (As answered here: [Graph/Gremlin for social media use case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51334950/graph-gremlin-for-social-media-use-case))
`g.V().has('id',1).as('me').out('follow').aggregate('followers').out('posted').group().by('postId').by(project('likedBySelf','likedByFollowing').by(__.in('liked').where(eq('me')).count()).by(__.in('liked').where(within('followers')).order().by(shuffle).values('id').fold()))`

Output:

```
[post1:[likedBySelf:0,likedByFollowing:[]],post2:[likedBySelf:1,likedByFollowing:[4,3]]]
```

This query is able to shuffle the values but shows all of the 'id's, now I want to select only the first 'id'. Using .next() instead of .fold() causes exception java.util.NoSuchElementException
**Is it possible to choose randomly without having to evaluate all the traversals first and then shuffling them?**

Desired Output:

```
[post1:[likedBySelf:0,likedByFollowing:[]],post2:[likedBySelf:1,likedByFollowing:[3]]]
```

Or

```
[post1:[likedBySelf:0,likedByFollowing:[]],post2:[likedBySelf:1,likedByFollowing:[4]]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're pretty close to your answer:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerGraph.open().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0], standard]
gremlin> g.addV('user').property('id',1).as('1').
......1>   addV('user').property('id',2).as('2').
......2>   addV('user').property('id',3).as('3').
......3>   addV('user').property('id',4).as('4').
......4>   addV('post').property('postId','post1').as('p1').
......5>   addV('post').property('postId','post2').as('p2').
......6>   addE('follow').from('1').to('2').
......7>   addE('follow').from('1').to('3').
......8>   addE('follow').from('1').to('4').
......9>   addE('posted').from('2').to('p1').
.....10>   addE('posted').from('2').to('p2').
.....11>   addE('liked').from('1').to('p2').
.....12>   addE('liked').from('3').to('p2').
.....13>   addE('liked').from('4').to('p2').iterate()
gremlin> g.V().has('id',1).as('me').
......1>   out('follow').
......2>   aggregate('followers').
......3>   out('posted').
......4>   group().
......5>     by('postId').
......6>     by(project('likedBySelf','likedByFollowing').
......7>          by(__.in('liked').where(eq('me')).count()).
......8>          by(__.in('liked').where(within('followers')).order().by('id',shuffle).values('id').limit(1).fold()))
==>[post2:[likedBySelf:1,likedByFollowing:[3]],post1:[likedBySelf:0,likedByFollowing:[]]]
```

I pretty much just added `limit(1)` so that only the first item after `shuffle` is selected. It took a few executions but I was able to see both of the outputs you were looking for with this method. As I suggested on your other question, you might also use `sample(1)`:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('id',1).as('me').
......1>   out('follow').
......2>   aggregate('followers').
......3>   out('posted').
......4>   group().
......5>     by('postId').
......6>     by(project('likedBySelf','likedByFollowing').
......7>          by(__.in('liked').where(eq('me')).count()).
......8>          by(__.in('liked').where(within('followers')).sample(1).values('id').fold()))
==>[post2:[likedBySelf:1,likedByFollowing:[3]],post1:[likedBySelf:0,likedByFollowing:[]]]
gremlin> g.V().has('id',1).as('me').
......1>   out('follow').
......2>   aggregate('followers').
......3>   out('posted').
......4>   group().
......5>     by('postId').
......6>     by(project('likedBySelf','likedByFollowing').
......7>          by(__.in('liked').where(eq('me')).count()).
......8>          by(__.in('liked').where(within('followers')).sample(1).values('id').fold()))
==>[post2:[likedBySelf:1,likedByFollowing:[4]],post1:[likedBySelf:0,likedByFollowing:[]]]
```