# Gremlin Azure Cosmos graphSON Complex Object

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

I am having a hard time understanding the way to return back data in gremlin syntax when you have vertices that combine to create a complex object.

my syntax below will be in gremlin syntax used with gremlin.net to access cosmos db - so the graphSON returned through cosmos and then my POCO object is in C# syntax.

Say I had an example that was more like a tree, where everything was related, but I didn't want repeated data.  So if I have a property - like an apt.  You have the Property vertex, Room vertices, People Vertices.  If I was doing a standard C# POCO, it may look like this:

```
public class Property{
   public List<Room> Rooms {get;set;}
   public List<Person> Managers {get;set;}
   //additional general properties of the property - name, address, etc
}

public class Room {
   public List<Person> Tenants {get;set;}
   //other room properties - number, size, etc
}

public class Person{
    //general properties - name, age, gender, etc
}
```

So I have been trying to somewhat replicate that structure in graphSON syntax, but once I get down one level, it doesn't really seem like that's what is done - at least I haven't found any examples.  I was expecting to be able to potentially get the graphSON to look more like this when returned:

```
"property":{
   "basic":{
      //the property vertex
    },
    "managers":[ //array of managers
       "manager":{
          //person vertex
       }
    ],
   "rooms":[ //array of rooms
        "room":{
          //a room vertex
         },
        "tenants":[
          {
            "tenant":{
               //person vertex
            }
          }
        ]
    ]
}
```

The one other caveat, is generally I may want certain properties returned or only parts and not the entire vertex - so most likely valueMap or something like that.
I've tried sideEffects, flatMap, maps, local in a variety of ways to see if I could get it, but it always seems to fall apart fairly quickly.

If I do a call like this:

```
g.V('my-key').as('property').flatmap(out('a-room')).as('r').select('property','r')
```

I'll get something more like this for return:

```
[
  {
    "property":{} //property vertex
    "r":{}//a room vertex
  },
  {
    "property":{} //property vertex
    "r":{}//a room vertex
  },
  //repeat until you have all rooms
]
```

that causes a lot of extra data returned because I only need property info once.

```
g.V('my-key').as('p').local(out('a-room').fold()).as('r').unfold().local(out('a-tenant').fold()).as('t').select('p','r','t')
```

That causes duplicate data again and keeps everything one level down and not sub levels.

So my question is: 
is the graphSON format I proposed possible?
Am I thinking in the wrong way when trying to pull back data? 
Is what I'm doing uncommon with graphDBs as I've had a hard time finding this type of single to multiple relationships with multi levels to create a complex object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When asking questions about Gremlin it's always best to include a brief Gremlin script that can create some sample data as it makes it incredibly easy for those who answer to give you an exact/tested traversal that can solve your problem ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51388315/1831717)).

As to your question, you can definitely return data in whatever form you need. It might help to read this recipe in the TinkerPop documentation on [Collections](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/#collections). In your case, I think you just need a nested `project()` type of traversal:

```
g.V("my-key").
  project('name','address', 'rooms')
    by('name').
    by('address').
    by(out('a-room').
       project('number','size','tenantCount')
         by('number').
         by('size').
         by(out('a-tenant').count()).
       fold())
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  Seeing it in that context really helps me understand project better and how it can be used.  I will make sure to include a script next time for sample data.  Thanks for the help and the link to the collections documentation as well.