# Gremlin query to groupcount edges and also return max/most recent date along with an identifier

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

I have a simple graph structure as follows:

Event-----HappenedAt------>Location

Event and Location vertices both have a name and id property.  HappenedAt edge has a date property (in ticks) called 'on'.

I am having trouble writing a query that for a given location (so starting with a known location) return a list of all distinct events that happened at that location, a count of the number of times each event happened (so groupcount of the happenedAt edges) and the max/most recent date each event occurred.

Ideally the output would look as follows for a given location:
Event Id, count, most recent/max date

Event A, 2, 5/27/2018

Event B, 2, 7/1/2018

I can get the group count and the max date just fine by themselves but can't seem to get the query right where those are combined into a single query to produce that output.

Probably simple, but I am new to Gremlin and Graph databases in general.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
g.addV('event').property('id','e1').property('name','Event A').as('e1').
  addV('event').property('id','e2').property('name','Event B').as('e2').
  addV('location').property('id','l1').property('name','Location 1').as('l1').
  addV('location').property('id','l2').property('name','Location 2').as('l2').
  addE('happenedAt').from('e1').to('l1').property('on','5/27/2018').
  addE('happenedAt').from('e1').to('l1').property('on','4/1/2018').
  addE('happenedAt').from('e2').to('l1').property('on','6/5/2018').
  addE('happenedAt').from('e2').to('l1').property('on', '7/1/2018').iterate()
```

Comment: When asking questions about Gremlin it is always helpful to people trying to answer your question if you provide a script that will create a sample graph - see here for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51388315/gremlin-choose-one-item-at-random

Comment: updated to include script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the first thing that came to mind for me - there may be other solutions:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('id','l1').
......1>   inE('happenedAt').
......2>   group().
......3>     by(outV().values('name')).
......4>   unfold().
......5>   project('event','count','mostRecent').
......6>     by(select(keys)).
......7>     by(select(values).count(local)).
......8>     by(select(values).unfold().values('on').max())
==>[event:Event B,count:2,mostRecent:7/1/2018]
==>[event:Event A,count:2,mostRecent:5/27/2018]
```

I `group()` on the edges at line 2-3 to get the unique events so basically at the end of that line 3 we have a `Map` where the key is the event name and the value is a list of the "happenedAt" edges for that event. That's the raw data you need to calculate what you need.

At line 4, I unfold the map to entries of that map and `project()` each entry into a new map of the data structure you requested. Note that with lines 7-8 I'm getting a `List` of edges from `select(values)`. That's why we use `local` in `count(local)` as we want to count the items in the `List` and not the `List` itself. Similarly, we `unfold()` the `List` in line 8 to pop off the "on" property values off the edges themselves to find the `max()`.

Comment: Outstanding, thank you so much.  Definitely would have floundered around for a long time before I would have come to that on my own.  Now I need to really dive in and understand fold/unfold and project so that I can put a query like this together on my own in the future.  Thanks again for the quick response!