# Gremlin query with nested vertices

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin, tinkerpop3, graph-traversal

My use case is:  `Bag` vertex has edge `holds` to `Box` vertex and `Box` vertex has edge `contains` to `Fruit` vertex. So it's a parent-child relation between 3 vertices.

Is it possible to write gremlin query which returns all related 3 vertices. for e.g  i need to fetch all Bags by `id` including `Box` vertex and further down to `Fruit` vertex for that Bag id. In SQL like syntax it's a simple `select * from bag where id = 1`.

sample structure:

```
g.addV('bag').property('id',1).property('name','bag1').property('size','12').as('1').
  addV('box').property('id',2).property('name','box1').property('width','12').as('2').
  addV('fruit').property('id',3).property('name','apple').property('color','red').as('3').
  addV('bag').property('id',4).property('name','bag2').property('size','44').as('4').
  addV('box').property('id',5).property('name','box2').property('width','14').as('5').
  addV('fruit').property('id',6).property('name','orange').property('color','yellow').as('6').
  addE('holds').from('1').to('2').
  addE('contains').from('2').to('3').
  addE('holds').from('4').to('5').
  addE('contains').from('5').to('6').iterate()
```

I want to get all properties of `1`, `2`, `3` when i query for vertices `1`.

I want the response in the below format.

`"bags" : [{
  "id":"1",
  "name":"bag1",
  "size" :"12",
  "boxes":[ { 
     "id" : "2",
     "name":"box1",
     "width" : "12",
     "fruits": [{
         "id":"3",
         "name" : "apple",
         "color" : "red"
     }]
  }]
},
{
  "id":"4",
  "name":"bag2",
  "size" : "44",
  "boxes":[ { 
     "id" : "5",
     "name":"box2",
      "width" : "44",
     "fruits": [{
         "id":"6",
         "name" : "orange"
         "color" : "yellow"
     }]
  }]
}]`

But not sure if similar case is possible in gremlin as there are no implicit relation between vertices.

Comment: Please consider updating your question with a Gremlin script that creates some sample data, as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51388315/gremlin-choose-one-item-at-random

Comment: good suggestion. i added basic data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would probably use `project()` to accomplish this:

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('bag').
......1>   project('id', 'name','boxes').
......2>     by('id').
......3>     by('name').
......4>     by(out('holds').
......5>        project('id','name','fruits').
......6>          by('id').
......7>          by('name').
......8>          by(out('contains').
......9>             project('id','name').
.....10>               by('id').
.....11>               by('name').
.....12>             fold()).
.....13>        fold())
==>[id:1,name:bag1,boxes:[[id:2,name:box1,fruits:[[id:3,name:apple]]]]]
==>[id:4,name:bag2,boxes:[[id:5,name:box2,fruits:[[id:6,name:orange]]]]]
```

I omitted the "bags" root level key as there were no other keys in the `Map` and it didn't seem useful to add that extra level.

Comment: Thanks @stephan. I updated my question with more data and sample response. please update your answer.

Comment: Nice one. If i have more properties than `id`, `name` then should  include all of them as `by('xxx')`. Is there any solution to include all the properties by default ?

Comment: In sql you wouldn't do `SELECT * FROM table` - you would be explicit with the fields - so including them individually is typically best. there are ways to do what you're asking though - you can read about them here: http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/#collections

Comment: Hi, the above query is breaking if i add any additional property to one of the vertex because previous data doesn't have that property. Any suggestion ?

Comment: there's a number of ways to deal with it. a simple way is to use `coalesce()` - http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#coalesce-step