# Graph/Gremlin query for social media use case

Tags: graph-databases, gremlin, amazon-neptune

Mine is a social network kind scenario. I want to get all the posts 'posted' by the people I follow. For each of these posts I want to know whether I have liked it or not and also the no of likes and comments that post have(only count) and latest 3 comments with all properties and all the properties of the commented user like his name etc. What is the best solution to get this in gremlin (possibly avoiding duplication)?

```
g.addV('user').property('id',1).as('1').
  addV('user').property('id',2).as('2').
  addV('user').property('id',3).as('3').
  addV('user').property('id',4).as('4').
  addV('post').property('postId','post1').as('p1').
  addV('post').property('postId','post2').as('p2').
  addV('comment').property('id','c1').property('text','hi').as('c1'). 
  addV('comment').property('id','c2').property('text','nice').as('c2'). 
  addV('comment').property('id','c3').property('text','hello').as('c3'). 
  addE('follow').from('1').to('2').
  addE('follow').from('1').to('3').
  addE('follow').from('1').to('4').
  addE('posted').from('2').to('p1').
  addE('posted').from('2').to('p2').
  addE('liked').from('1').to('p2').
  addE('liked').from('3').to('p2').
  addE('liked').from('4').to('p2').
  addE('commented').from('1').to('c1'). 
  addE('comments').from('c1').to('p1'). 
  addE('commented').from('2').to('c2'). 
  addE('comments').from('c2').to('p2').iterate()
```

Comment: Could you please provide a Gremlin script that creates some sample data - here is an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51388315/gremlin-choose-one-item-at-random

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `commented` edges should have a timestamp property, that's why the following query still has the todo in it, but I guess it should be easy to figure the remaining part out yourself.

```
g.V().has('user','id',1).as('me').
  out('follow').as('friend').
  out('posted').as('post').                                     /* all the posts 'posted' by the people I follow */
  project('friend','post','liked','likes','comments','latest').
    by(select('friend')).
    by(select('post').by('postId')).
    by(coalesce(__.in('liked').where(eq('me')).constant('yes'),
                constant('no'))).                               /* whether I have liked it or not                */
    by(inE('liked').count()).                                   /* no of likes                                   */
    by(inE('comments').count()).                                /* comments that post have(only count)           */
    by(__.in('comments').as('comment').                         /* todo: order by time desc                      */
       in('commented').as('user').limit(3).                     /* latest 3 comments                             */
       select('comment','user').
         by(valueMap()).                                        /* with all properties                           */
       fold())
```

Result for the sample graph:

```
==>[friend:v[2],post:post1,liked:no,likes:0,comments:1,latest:[[comment:[id:[c1],text:[hi]],user:[id:[1]]]]]
==>[friend:v[2],post:post2,liked:yes,likes:3,comments:1,latest:[[comment:[id:[c2],text:[nice]],user:[id:[2]]]]]
```

Comment: Please consider reading the Getting Started tutorial: http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/tutorials/getting-started/

Comment: If you have millions of users, you'll likely be able to afford reasonably sized clusters that perform quite well on this kind of queries. Also, caching becomes a huge thing if you have a ton of concurrent requests, and then it's no longer a question about the underlying storage and query engine.

Comment: Memcached, Redis, etc., when used as a caching layer, are not designed to work with particular databases, you can use them for pretty much everything, you don't even need a database.

Comment: I don't know what all these big companies are using, but social networks are pretty much the most common use-case for graph databases. What you ultimately decide on, depends on your performance-, scalability- and reliability-requirements. That said, you can build a social network site with any underlying database technology - so it should be whatever works best for you.

Comment: In TP 3.4.0 you'll be able to do `valueMap().by(unfold())`. In current versions you can `unfold()` the value map und re-`group()` it.

Comment: Since you're using Neptune, this should help: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-gremlin-rest.html -- note, that you'll find this kind of general questions almost always answered in the docs.