# Why does SELECT then performing a step like hasId() change what was selected?

Tags: gremlin

Am I not using select() properly in my code? When I re-select("pair") for some reason, what it contained originally has been updated after performing some step. Shouldn't what was labeled using as() preserve what was contained?

```
g.V()
.hasLabel("Project")
.hasId("parentId","childId").as("pair")
.select("pair")
.hasId("parentId").as("parent")
.select("pair") // no longer what it was originally set to
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is expected. You (presumably) find two vertices with `hasId("parentId","childId")` and so the first `select("pair")` would of course show each vertex.  But, then you filter again, `hasId("parentId")` and kill the traverser that contains the vertex with the id of "childId". It gets filtered away and therefore never triggers the second/last `select("pair")` step and would only therefore return the one vertex that has the id of "parentId".

Comment: After some thinking, it makes more sense now. However, I am finding it difficult to think of a way to achieve what I'm trying to do without having to fetch V() again. Do you have any suggestions? I was thinking using next() twice to label them both but that doesn't seem like the ideal approach.

Comment: maybe consider asking a new question that contains more specifics on what you are trying to do, perhaps with some sample data as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51388315/gremlin-choose-one-item-at-random

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. What I asked is completely different from the original question, so I agree.