# Traverse through graph based on edge's properties values | Gremlin

Tags: graph, gremlin, graph-traversal

I have a graph in which all Edges have the same property but values may differ between Vertices. I need to traverse through the graph from an specific vertex though all edges that have an specific value for that proerty.

For example I have this graph:

[example graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWIBX.png)

From **Vertex: A** traverse through all vertices where the edges `color == blue`.
The expected answer should be: *[A, B, D, C, H, G]*

Comment: I was trying something like this:
``g.V('A').until(has("color", neq("blue"))).repeat(outE()).inV().dedup()``

Comment: the picture is nice, but when asking questions about Gremlin a sample data script is even better - here is an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51388315/gremlin-choose-one-item-at-random

Answer (score 1):

The query you've tried only checks vertex properties and it makes `blue` a break condition, not a continuation condition.

This is what you're looking for:

```
g.V('A').emit().repeat(outE().has("color", "blue").inV().dedup())
```

Comment: That query was the one I was expecting. Thanks!