# Gremlin, 1-to-N relationship query issue

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3

I'm new to Gremlin. Struggling to get this one right. Any help would be really appreciated.

I have the Comments(C), Plans(P) and Users(U) enter code here data in below format.

```
C3 - CommentsOn -> P1
C2 - CommentsOn -> P1
C1 - CommentsOn -> P1

U2 - Likes -> C3
U4 - Likes -> C3
U1 - Likes -> C1
U1 - Likes -> C2
```

Now I need to get the data in below format

```
[
 {
  "Comment": C3,
  "LikedBy": [{U2},{U4}]
 },
 {
  "Comment": C2,
  "LikedBy": [{U1}]
 },
 {
  "Comment": C1,
  "LikedBy": [{U1}]
 }
]
```

Meaning, I need to get the list of comments and their corresponding likes.

Answer (score 1):

In the future, you might consider including a Gremlin script that creates a small sample dataset so that you can get a tested answer ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51388315/gremlin-choose-one-item-at-random)). Anyway, the answer here is to use `project()`:

```
g.V().hasLabel('Comment').
  project('Comment','LikedBy').
    by().
    by(__.in('Likes').fold())
```