# Is there way to merge outgoing Vertices of two known Vertices by their ID

Tags: gremlin

I am new to Graph DBs in general and trying to learn Gremlin QL. I was wondering if there is a way to directly merge two immediate neighbors of two vertices who ids are known. For example, in the below graph

[image]

I don't want to traverse the entire graph, I just want the two subgraphs to merge based on their common neighbors and sort based on the sum of the weights of the two edges leading to the same Vertex.

In the above graph, I want to be able to display the vertices `A, B, C, D` when I query with the vertices `1 and 2`. I want to be able to merge the outE of vertex 1 and vertex 2, aggregate the weights of (edge 1 -> A and Edge 2 -> A), (edge 1 -> B and Edge 2 -> B), (edge 1 -> C and Edge 2 -> C) and (edge 1 -> D and Edge 2 -> D) and sort the result based on this combined score.

The code for the graph creation is below

```
g.addV().property('id',1).property("type","A").as('1')
  addV().property('id',2).property("type","B").as('2').
  addV().property('id',A).property("type","X").as('A').
  addV().property('id',B).property("type","X").as('B').
  addV().property('id',C).property("type","X").as('C').
  addV().property('id',D).property("type","X").as('D').
  addE('connects').from('1').to('A').property("weight",0.1d)
  addE('connects').from('1').to('B').property("weight",0.4d)
  addE('connects').from('1').to('C').property("weight",0.2d)
  addE('connects').from('1').to('D').property("weight",0.7d)
  addE('connects').from('2').to('A').property("weight",0.5d)
  addE('connects').from('2').to('B').property("weight",0.2d)
  addE('connects').from('2').to('C').property("weight",0.7d)
  addE('connects').from('2').to('D').property("weight",0.4d).iterate()
```

If I were to represent the above data in an SQL, a sample model is as below

```
create table items(id varchar(20), toId varchar(20), weight double(5,4), primary key (id, toId);

insert into items values("1","A",0.1);
insert into items values("1","B",0.4);
insert into items values("1","C",0.2);
insert into items values("1","D",0.7);
insert into items values("2","A",0.5);
insert into items values("2","B",0.2);
insert into items values("2","C",0.7);
insert into items values("2","D",0.4);

select toId, a.weight+b.weight as weight from items a, items b where a.id = "1" and b.id = "2" and a.toId = b.toId order by weight desc;
```

This typically returns

```
D, 0.11
C, 0.9
B, 0.6
A, 0.5
```

Any help in this is highly appreciated.

Comment: The picture is nice but could you please provide a Gremlin script that creates some sample data - here is an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51388315/gremlin-choose-one-item-at-random

Comment: Updated the graph creation per Stephen's comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some adjustments to your data creation script as it had some syntax errors:

```
g.addV().property('id',1).property("type","A").as('1').
  addV().property('id',2).property("type","B").as('2').
  addV().property('id','A').property("type","X").as('A').
  addV().property('id','B').property("type","X").as('B').
  addV().property('id','C').property("type","X").as('C').
  addV().property('id','D').property("type","X").as('D').
  addE('connects').from('1').to('A').property("weight",0.1d).
  addE('connects').from('1').to('B').property("weight",0.4d).
  addE('connects').from('1').to('C').property("weight",0.2d).
  addE('connects').from('1').to('D').property("weight",0.7d).
  addE('connects').from('2').to('A').property("weight",0.1d).
  addE('connects').from('2').to('B').property("weight",0.4d).
  addE('connects').from('2').to('C').property("weight",0.2d).
  addE('connects').from('2').to('D').property("weight",0.7d).iterate()
```

There might be some other ways to do this, but in my approach to writing the query I decided to start by collecting the edges that we needed between the two start vertices of "1" and "2":

```
gremlin> g.V().has('id',1).
......1>   outE('connects').as('1e').
......2>   inV().as('v').
......3>   inE('connects').as('2e').
......4>   where(outV().has('id',2)).
......5>   select('1e','v','2e')
==>[1e:e[18][0-connects->6],v:v[6],2e:e[22][3-connects->6]]
==>[1e:e[19][0-connects->9],v:v[9],2e:e[23][3-connects->9]]
==>[1e:e[20][0-connects->12],v:v[12],2e:e[24][3-connects->12]]
==>[1e:e[21][0-connects->15],v:v[15],2e:e[25][3-connects->15]]
```

So the above gives us all the shared edges and plus the vertices we want to sum the weights for. You can do the summation with `group()` step:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('id',1).
......1>   outE('connects').as('1e').
......2>   inV().as('v').
......3>   inE('connects').as('2e').
......4>   where(outV().has('id',2)).
......5>   select('1e','v','2e').
......6>   group().
......7>     by(select('v').by('id')).
......8>     by(select(values).
......9>        unfold().has('weight').
.....10>        values('weight').sum())
==>[A:0.2,B:0.8,C:0.4,D:1.4]
```

The first `by()` modulator grabs the "v" key from the incoming `Map` of results and extracts the "id" property from the vertex within it. The second `by()` modulator produces the sum by doing something that might not immediately be clear. It gets the values from the incoming `Map` (i.e. the vertex and related edges) then finds only those elements with the edge property of "weight" (the vertex will be filtered out). Finally, it sums those weight values.

This bit of Gremlin might be tuned a bit too much to the data in your example. In the event the graph structure creates more than these simple paths I imagine that you'd see some edge duplication in your output. If you don't care about the duplication and you want to sum it all then I suppose what I have will work as-is. If you only want to count unique edge weights in your sum then you probably need to add a `dedup()` step after the `has('weight')`.

If you need to order the result then you can add the `order()` step and order by the `values` in the `Map` result:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('id',1).
......1>   outE('connects').as('1e').
......2>   inV().as('v').
......3>   inE('connects').as('2e').
......4>   where(outV().has('id',2)).
......5>   select('1e','v','2e').
......6>   group().
......7>     by(select('v').by('id')).
......8>     by(select(values).
......9>        unfold().has('weight').
.....10>        values('weight').sum()).
.....11>   order(local).by(values, desc)
==>[D:1.4,B:0.8,C:0.4,A:0.2]
```

Note that you use `local` because you are ordering within the current `Map` of the traversal stream and not ordering the stream itself.

Comment: How can I sort the result in a descending order based on the sum of weights?

Comment: Getting an error when I am trying this
    g.V().has('id',1).
    ......1> outE('connects').as('1e').
    ......2> inV().as('v').
    ......3> inE('connects').as('2e').
    ......4> where(outV().has('id',2)).
    ......5> select('1e','v','2e').
    ......6> group().
    ......7>   by(select('v').by('id')).
    ......8>   by(select(values).
    ......9>      unfold().has('weight').
    .....10>      values('weight').sum().as('sum')).
    .....11> order().
    .....12> by(select('sum'))

The provided traverser does not map to a value: {...}->[SelectOneStep(last,sum)]

Comment: updated the answer to include sorting. i can't really read what you pasted in the comment regarding your error but i imagine it's related to your attempt at `order()`. see my approach above in the revised answer