# How to sort elements in subquery locally in gremlin?

Tags: gremlin

Let's assume we have a graph of persons, with properties

- `name` (String)
- `age` (int)

... and `friend` edges in between some of them. Let's further assume we have a complex gremlin query which eventually produces person vertices.

Now, for each of the resulting persons, we want to find the **three oldest friends** in a subquery.

This is the rough query structure:

```
g.traversal.V()
    // complex filtering and navigation here, produces person vertices
    .flatMap(
        __.out(friend)
        .order().by("age", desc)
        .limit(3)
    )
    // complex query continues with the three oldest friends per input vertex here
```

The problem with this query is that the `order().by(...)` step is **global**. I get three persons *in total* for all person vertices which enter the `flatMap(...)`.

What I would like to receive is (up to) three persons ***per vertex* entering the flatMap(...)** step.

How would you do that in gremlin? I've read that there is "local" scoping of sorts, but I was unable to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect your traversal to work as you would wish it to. See my examples with TinkerGraph and the "modern" toy graph:

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('person').flatMap(out().order().by(id))
==>v[2]
==>v[3]
==>v[4]
==>v[3]
==>v[5]
==>v[3]
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('person').flatMap(out().order().by(id).limit(1))
==>v[2]
==>v[3]
==>v[3]
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('person').flatMap(out().order().by(id).limit(2))
==>v[2]
==>v[3]
==>v[3]
==>v[5]
==>v[3]
```

Or perhaps easier to see in action with just `map()`:

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('person').map(out().order().by(id).fold())
==>[v[2],v[3],v[4]]
==>[]
==>[v[3],v[5]]
==>[v[3]]
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('person').map(out().order().by(id).limit(1).fold())
==>[v[2]]
==>[]
==>[v[3]]
==>[v[3]]
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('person').map(out().order().by(id).limit(2).fold())
==>[v[2],v[3]]
==>[]
==>[v[3],v[5]]
==>[v[3]]
```

Perhaps there is something in your data that you are not expecting? If the problem persists maybe you could debug with `map()` as I showed above and see what's being returned before the lists are flattened? If all else fails, please update your question with a [script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51388315/gremlin-choose-one-item-at-random) that provides some sample data and a Gremlin Console session demonstrating the failure with that data.

Comment: The problem isn't flat map, it's the `order().by(...)`. I want the 3 *oldest* friends of each person. The order by waits for all other traversers (i.e. it acts as a globally blocking step), and the output of my flat map is always at most 3 persons. I would like to have the 3 oldest persons per vertex that arrives as input to `flatMap()`.

Comment: I understand the problem, but I was trying to demonstrate that I can't recreate it. I updated my answer to include `order()` and I can see no such restriction where I globally only get 3 results total. am i still missing something? can you demonstrate the problem in a console session as I suggested? what graph database are you using...perhaps there is a bug in their implementation?

Comment: Hm... you're right, I just tried it myself on TinkerGraph. Maybe I was jumping to conclusions too quickly. The gremlin query surrounding this `flatMap(...)` was quite complex, so maybe I made a mistake somewhere else. Thanks, I appreciate the effort!