# Gremlin search for vertexes related to 2 or more specific nodes

Tags: graph, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I'm trying to produce a Gremlin query whereby I need to find vertexes which have edges from specific other vertexes. The less abstract version of this query is I have user vertexes, and those are related to group vertexes (i.e subjects in a school, so students who are in "Year 6 Maths" and "Year 6 English" etc). An extra difficulty is the ability for subgroups to exist in this query.

The query I need to find those users who are in 2 or more groups specified by the user.

Currently I have a brief solution, but in production usage using Amazon Netpune this query performs way too poorly, even with a small amount of data. I'm sure there's a simpler way of achieving this :/

```
g.V()
.has('id', 'group_1')
.repeat(out("STUDENT", "SUBGROUP"))
.until(hasLabel("USER"))
.aggregate("q-1")
.V()
.has('id', 'group_2')
.repeat(out("STUDENT", "SUBGROUP"))
.until(hasLabel("USER"))
.where(within("q-1"))
.aggregate("q-2")
.V()
.hasLabel(USER)
.where(within("q-2"))
# We add some more filtering here, such as search terms
.dedup()
.range(0, 10)
.values("id")
.toList()
```

Answer (score 0):

The first major change you can do is to not bother iterating all of `V()` again for "USER" - that's already that output from the prior steps so collecting "q-2" just to use it for a filter doesn't seem necessary:

```
g.V().
  has('id', 'group_1').
  repeat(out("STUDENT", "SUBGROUP")).
    until(hasLabel("USER")).
  aggregate("q-1").
  V().
  has('id', 'group_2').
  repeat(out("STUDENT", "SUBGROUP")).
    until(hasLabel("USER")).
  where(within("q-1")).
  # We add some more filtering here, such as search terms
  dedup().
  range(0, 10).
  values("id")
```

That should already be a huge savings to your query because that change avoids iterating the entire graph in memory (i.e. full scan of all vertices) as there was no index lookup there.

I don't know what your additional filters are here:

```
# We add some more filtering here, such as search terms
```

but I would definitely look to try to filter the users earlier in your query rather than later. Perhaps consider using `emit()` on your `repeats()` to filter better. You should probably also `dedup()` your "q-1" and reduce the size of the list there.

I'd be curious to know how much just the initial change I suggested works as that was probably the biggest bulk of your query cost (unless you have a really deep/wide tree of student/subgroups I guess). Perhaps there is more that could be tweaked here though, but it would be nice to know that you at least have a traversal with satisfying performance at this point.

Comment: One of the difficulties we have is one of the extra filters we apply is checking if the user belongs to any one of another list of groups we provide :/

Comment: Ok...aggregate "q-2" so that you can do your extra check, but apply the other change to get rid of the full scan and let me know what you're seeing in terms of a performance improvement. After that, it might be helpful if you provide some sample data in the form of a Gremlin script along with the exact output you're looking for with all required filters so that a fully tested traversal can be provided as an answer that looks at your problem in totality. here is an example of the type of script that would be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51388315/gremlin-choose-one-item-at-random