# How to sort by social connections using neptune graph database

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

### Question

How would I sort a list of users in a graph database by the count of edges I have to the users in the list.

### Background

Getting to know AWS Neptune graph database and was wondering whether my use case is an appropriate use of the graph database, how to implement, and whether it would be performant.

### Given

Nodes: users, classes, groups
Edges: user-following, user-groups, user-classes

### Requirement

Return a list of users sorted by the number of their social connections to me.  Social connections defined by users I follow, users that follow me, groups we share, and classes that we share.  We would weight each connection factor by a different multiplier depending on how we want to tune the social connections.

Comment: Could you please provide a Gremlin script that creates some sample data - here is an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51388315/gremlin-choose-one-item-at-random

Comment: Hi, do you have any updates on this?