# Gremlin: Calculate division of based on two counts in one line of code

Tags: orientdb, gremlin

I have two counts, calculated as follows:

1)g.V().hasLabel('brand').where(__.inE('client_brand').count().is(gt(0))).count()

2)g.V().hasLabel('brand').count()

and I want to get one line of code that results in the first count divided by the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
g.V().hasLabel('brand').
  fold().as('a','b').
  math('a/b').
    by(unfold().where(inE('client_brand')).count())
    by(unfold().count())
```

Note that I simplify the first traversal to just `.where(inE('client_brand')).count()` since you only care to count that there is at least one edge, there's no need to count them all and do a compare.

You could also `union()` like:

```
g.V().hasLabel('brand').
  union(where(inE('client_brand')).count(),
        count())
  fold().as('a','b').
  math('a/b').
    by(limit(local,1))
    by(tail(local))
```

While the first one was a bit easier to read/follow, I guess the second is nicer because it only stores a list of the two counts whereas, the first stores a list of all the "brand" vertices which would be more memory intensive I guess.

Yet another way, provided by Daniel Kuppitz, that uses `groupCount()` in an interesting way:

```
g.V().hasLabel('brand').
  groupCount().
    by(choose(inE('client_brand'),
                constant('a'),
                constant('b'))).
  math('a/(a+b)')
```

The following solution that uses `sack()` step shows why we have `math()` step:

```
g.V().hasLabel('brand').
  groupCount().
    by(choose(inE('client_brand'),
                constant('a'),
                constant('b'))).
  sack(assign).
    by(coalesce(select('a'), constant(0))).
  sack(mult).
    by(constant(1.0)). /* we need a double */
  sack(div).
    by(select(values).sum(local)).
  sack()
```

If you can use lambdas then:

```
g.V().hasLabel('brand').
  union(where(inE('client_brand')).count(),
        count())
  fold().
  map{ it.get()[0]/it.get()[1]}
```

Comment: Hi Stephen, thank you! Unfortunately I am getting this error when I try to run the first one: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.DefaultGraphTraversal.math() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [a/b] Possible solutions: max(), max(groovy.lang.Closure), with(groovy.lang.Closure), max(java.util.Comparator), each(groovy.lang.Closure), each(groovy.lang.Closure)

Comment: 'brand' has properties name, id, description, and entityNameType, and incoming edge 'client_brand', and 'client' has the same properties.

Comment: `math()` step was introduced in TinkerPop 3.3.0 - perhaps you are on an old version? daniel kuppitz mentioned yet another way to do this with `math()` step which i just added to my answer as he didn't feel like adding another one. if things still don't work once you sorted out the issue with `math()` i suggest providing some sample data if you have other issues to address: - here is an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51388315/gremlin-choose-one-item-at-random

Answer (score -3):

This is what worked for me:

```
g.V().limit(1).project('client_brand_count','total_brands')
.by(g.V().hasLabel('brand')
.where(__.inE('client_brand').count().is(gt(0))).count())
.by(g.V().hasLabel('brand').count())
.map{it.get().values()[0] / it.get().values()[1]}
.project('brand_client_pct')
```

Comment: well, you can use closures, but they should be a last resort which is why they were not part of my suggestions or kuppitz's suggestions. a closure reduces the portability of your code as they do not work in all environments. i also think think that if you still intend to use lambdas you can massively reduce the complexity of your proposed solution. i updated my answer again with a lambda solution that should be much more direct. consider doing a `profile()` on both to see the difference in what's happening.