# Gremlin: how can I create a dynamic filter to only show results that have a date later than 2 days from now?

Tags: orientdb, gremlin

I have vertex "project" with properties "name" and "createdDate". I want to dynamically filter the projects to only show those that were created in the last two days, by "name", without having to hardcode the date into the filter.  Is this possible?

I have this so far, which is not giving me an error but not producing results:
`g.V().hasLabel('project').has('createdDate',gt('{LocalTime.Now()}'-2))`

If I try this, I see all results but I want to filter by date:
`g.V().hasLabel('project').has('createdDate',lt('{LocalTime.Now()}'))`

Comment: What's the data type of your `createdDate` properties?

Comment: Sample data always makes a question clear and allows you to get a tested answer. Here is an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51388315/gremlin-choose-one-item-at-random