# How to use less than inside option of CHOOSE step in gremlin

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop

```
.choose(values('points')
  .option(lt(500), updating the vertex properties)
  .option(gt(500), updating and creating new properties)
  .option(none,creating new vertex ))
```

points is vertex property of type integer

I want to perform **less than** and **greater than** operations inside **option**. I am trying in the above way.Please correct me if I am wrong.

If there is any other way to perform this please let me know.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature hasn't been implemented as of Apache TinkerPop 3.4.2. It is a long standing open issue: [TINKERPOP-1084](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP-1084). I think that if you want this functionality, you're going to have do a nested `choose()`:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerFactory.createModern().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('person').
......1>   choose(values('age').is(lt(29)),
......2>          constant('lt29'),
......3>          choose(values('age').is(gt(29)),
......4>                 constant('gt29'),
......5>                 constant('29')))
==>29
==>lt29
==>gt29
==>gt29
```

Note that you aren't restricted to `constant()` as a result of these nested `choose()` operations. You can add any anonymous traversal you like there as in:

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('person').
......1>   choose(values('age').is(lt(29)),
......2>          constant('lt29'),
......3>          choose(values('age').is(gt(29)),
......4>                 math('_ - 29').by('age'),
......5>                 constant('29')))
==>29
==>lt29
==>3.0
==>6.0
```

Comment: If the values of age is **gt29** then I want to **subtract**  29 from age.I think to achieve this I have to store the value of age inside the query.Is it possible to store the values inside query.If possible,how can I store the values.Otherwise how can I achieve this.                                   .                                                                               Thank you

Comment: you can just use `math()` step

Comment: Thanks for answering Mr.Stephen.Subtraction can be done through math step.But in my case I am referring to points.Let us take an example **vertex  as   AddPts** containing **totalPoints** as property.After adding specific(ex:20) points to the property it should not exceed 500.If it is going to exceed 500.Then I need to add those extra points by adding new vertex.For this I need get the current vertex property **totalPoints**  value and subtract the value from 500. Can you give a example for this.

Comment: Well, you know you have `math()` step to do calculations. Why not just change line 1 to `choose(values('totalPoints').math('_+20').is(lt(500))` then you don't actually modify the property value until you know if it exceeds your limit. if you need a working example, i suggest that you write a new question with some sample data like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51388315/gremlin-choose-one-item-at-random

Comment: Thank you Mr.Stephen.I wrote new question with sample data.Can you please check it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56580992/gremlin-adding-new-vertex-if-it-exceeds-the-limit].