# Gremlin - adding new vertex if it exceeds the limit

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop

Sample data:

I have two vertices by names User , Points

First adding data for vertex **User**

```
g.addV('User').property('id',1).
  addV('User').property('id',2).
  addV('User').property('id',3).iterate()
```

Now adding **Points** vertices and connecting **addingPoints** Edge from **User** to **Points**

```
g.V().hasLabel('User').has('id',1).as('curUser1').
  V().hasLabel('User').has('id',2).as('curUser2').
  V().hasLabel('User').has('id',3).as('curUser3').
  addV('Points').property('totalPoints',0).property('userPoints',0).
  property('createDate',1560316666).property('name','user1').
  addE('addingPoints').from('curUser1').
  addV('Points').property('totalPoints',0).property('userPoints',0).
  property('createDate',1560318666).property('name','user2').
  addE('addingPoints').from('curUser2').
  addV('Points').property('totalPoints',0).property('userPoints',0).
  property('createDate',1560318657).property('name','user3').
  addE('addingPoints').from('curUser3').iterate()
```

Now each **User** is  having atleast one **Points** vertex.

Now I want to add 10 (or) 20 (or) 30 points randomly to **totalPoints** Property of user with **id** as 1

while adding the points, I  have three cases:

1.If **totalPoints** are lt500 Then I just need to update the **totalPoints** property of **Points** vertex of user with **id** as 1.

2.If **totalPoints** are eq500 Then I should create new **Points** vertex and add points to **totalPoints** property of **Points** vertex of user with **id** as 1.

3.If **totalPoints** are 490 which is not eq500 but lt500. But now if I need to add 30 points to the **totalPoints** property 
then I need to add 10 points to the old **Points** vertex of user with **id** as 1 and I should add remaining 20 points to new **Points** vertex of user with **id** as 1.

How can I achieve this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Pick the user's `Points` vertex with the lowest `totalPoints` value.
2. Sum the `totalPoints` with the new number of points.
3. If the sum exceeds 500, set the `totalPoints` property value to 500 and add a new `Points` vertex with a `totalPoints` value of `sum-500`.
4. If the sum doesn't exceed 500, set it as the new `totalPoints` property value.

These 4 steps translated into a traversal:

```
g.withSack(points).
  V().has('User','id',user).as('u').
    out('addingPoints').
    order().
      by('totalPoints').
    limit(1).
    sack(sum).
      by('totalPoints').
    choose(sack().is(gt(maxPoints)),
             sack(minus).
               by(constant(maxPoints)).
             property('totalPoints', maxPoints).
             addV('Points').
             sideEffect(addE('addingPoints').
                          from('u'))).
    property('totalPoints', sack())
```

And a small console example (I initialized the first `Points` vertex with `totalPoints=400` and the second `Points` vertex with `totalPoints=480`):

```
gremlin> showUserPoints = {
......1>   g.V().as('u').out('addingPoints').
......2>     group().
......3>       by(select('u').by('id')).
......4>       by('totalPoints').next()
......5> }
==>groovysh_evaluate$_run_closure1@7c2b58c0

gremlin> addPoints = { user, points, maxPoints = 500 ->
......1>   g.withSack(points).
......2>     V().has('User','id',user).as('u').
......3>       out('addingPoints').
......4>       order().
......5>         by('totalPoints').
......6>       limit(1).
......7>       sack(sum).
......8>         by('totalPoints').
......9>       choose(sack().is(gt(maxPoints)),
.....10>                sack(minus).
.....11>                  by(constant(maxPoints)).
.....12>                property('totalPoints', maxPoints).
.....13>                addV('Points').
.....14>                sideEffect(addE('addingPoints').
.....15>                             from('u'))).
.....16>       property('totalPoints', sack()).iterate()
.....17> 
.....17>   showUserPoints()
.....18> }
==>groovysh_evaluate$_run_closure1@31d6f3fe

gremlin> showUserPoints()
==>1=[400]
==>2=[480]
==>3=[0]

gremlin> addPoints(1, 10)
==>1=[410]
==>2=[480]
==>3=[0]
gremlin> addPoints(1, 90)
==>1=[500]
==>2=[480]
==>3=[0]
gremlin> addPoints(2, 30)
==>1=[500]
==>2=[500, 10]
==>3=[0]
gremlin> addPoints(2, 40)
==>1=[500]
==>2=[500, 50]
==>3=[0]
gremlin> addPoints(3, 100)
==>1=[500]
==>2=[500, 50]
==>3=[100]
```