# Follow a certain relationship (edge with a certain label) between the same kind of vertices (vertices that share the same label) in gremlin

Tags: graph-databases, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I am tasked with writing a query for a front-end application that visualizes a Neptune Graph database. Let us say that the first vertex are items while the second vertex user. A user can create an item. There are item to item relationships to show items derived from another item like in the case of media clips cut out of an original media clip. The first set of items created should be created in a vertex such as a `SERVER` which they are grouped by in the UI.

The following is the requirement:

```
Filtering on a vertex shows the full graph for that vertex:
(1) Follow all ITEM - ITEM relationships
(2) Show any ITEM - USER relationships up to 1 hop (i.e. further ITEMs linked to a USER not shown already by (1) should not be displayed)
```

Here is a visual representation of the graph.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YNzh4wbzcdC0JeloMgD2C0oS6MYvfI4q/view?usp=sharing

A sample code to reproduce this graph is below. This graph could even get deeper. This is a just a simple example. Kindly see diagram:

```
g.addV('SERVER').property(id, 'server1')
g.addV('SERVER').property(id, 'server2')
g.addV('ITEM').property(id, 'item1')
g.addV('ITEM').property(id, 'item2')
g.addV('ITEM').property(id, 'item3')
g.addV('ITEM').property(id, 'item4')
g.addV('USER').property(id, 'user1')


g.V('item1').addE('STORED IN').to(g.V('server1'))
g.V('item2').addE('STORED IN').to(g.V('server2'))
g.V('item2').addE('RELATED TO').to(g.V('item1'))
g.V('item3').addE('DERIVED FROM').to(g.V('item2') )
g.V('item3').addE('CREATED BY').to(g.V('user1'))
```

The result should be in the form below if possible:

```
[
 [
   {
     "V1": {},
     "E": {},
     "V2": {}
   }
 ]
]
```

We have an API with an endpoint that allows for open-ended gremlin queries. We call this endpoint in our client app to fetch the data that is rendered visually. I have written a query that provides just one hop between items but does not walk the whole graph database.

```
g.V('${id}').as('V1').bothE().dedup().as('E')
    .otherV().hasLabel(within('USER','ITEM')).as('V2').path().limit(500).select('V1', 'E', 'V2').fold()
```

I would appreciate if I can get a single query that will fetch this dataset if it is possible. If the vertex for the provided vertex's id is not connected to anything, I would want to retrieve it and render it alone on the UI.

Comment: @stephen-mallette, I know that you are an expert on this. Can you help me with this, please? Thank you very much.

Comment: @daniel-kuppitz, please kindly help with this. Thank you very much.

Comment: I can't quite follow the problem description. Could you provide a small sample graph?

Comment: @daniel-kuppitz, thank you very much. I have edited my post and added a simple image of the graph. You can see it here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YNzh4wbzcdC0JeloMgD2C0oS6MYvfI4q/view?usp=sharing. I will be glad if you can help with a query to walk the whole graph for all item -> item edges, showing the vertices, edges, and destination vertices as well as the vertices' properties in a way that I can get the data to visualise the graph in a front end. Thank you very much.

Comment: Diagrams are nice, but code to create a sample graph would be even better. E.g. like shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56922227/gremlin-find-highest-match
It definitely increases the response time, if people who want to answer don't have to come up with their own sample graph that matches your problem domain. Also, you don't mention what kind of output format you would prefer. If that means, you can take vertices and edges in any arbitrary order, good, otherwise, you should be more specific.

Comment: @DanielKuppitz, I have now added a sample query and sample results. Thank you so much for your help. I am so sorry for not having come up with the code earlier.

Comment: @stephen-mallette

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood all the rules correctly, then the following query should produce the desired result:

```
g.V('${id}').aggregate('v1').
  repeat(__.as('V1').bothE().dedup().as('E').otherV().hasLabel('USER','ITEM').as('V2').
         aggregate('x').by(select('V1', 'E', 'V2'))).
    until(hasLabel('USER')).
  as('V1').bothE().dedup().as('E').otherV().hasLabel('ITEM').as('V2').
  aggregate('x').
    by(select('V1', 'E', 'V2')).
  cap('v1','x','v1').
  coalesce(select('x').unfold(),
           select('v1').unfold().project('V1'))
```

Executed on your sample graph it yields:

```
gremlin> g.V('server1').aggregate('v1').
......1>   repeat(__.as('V1').bothE().dedup().as('E').otherV().hasLabel('USER','ITEM').as('V2').
......2>          aggregate('x').by(select('V1', 'E', 'V2'))).
......3>     until(hasLabel('USER')).
......4>   as('V1').bothE().dedup().as('E').otherV().hasLabel('ITEM').as('V2').
......5>   aggregate('x').
......6>     by(select('V1', 'E', 'V2')).
......7>   cap('v1','x','v1').
......8>   coalesce(select('x').unfold(),
......9>            select('v1').unfold().project('V1'))
==>[V1:v[server1],E:e[0][item1-STORED IN->server1],V2:v[item1]]
==>[V1:v[item1],E:e[2][item2-RELATED TO->item1],V2:v[item2]]
==>[V1:v[item2],E:e[3][item3-DERIVED FROM->item2],V2:v[item3]]
==>[V1:v[item3],E:e[4][item3-CREATED BY->user1],V2:v[user1]]
==>[V1:v[user1],E:e[4][item3-CREATED BY->user1],V2:v[item3]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try this out but does `until(hasLabel('USER'))` fulfill the one hop requirement while the rest of the traversal continues following all ITEM -> ITEM relationships till the end of the graph?

Comment: I came across this condition somewhere that aids walking the whole graph - `.until(outE().count().is(0))`

Comment: The rest of the traversal is not a `repeat()`, it's just one more hop.

Comment: It looks great. I just want to quickly integrate it with the frontend and see how it looks. But it shows the full graph for that vertex, right? What about handling of duplicates?

Comment: I just saw the dedup() step that you added to the edges. Thanks a lot. This looks great. I will mark this as answer in a bit. Let me do few tests.

Comment: I noticed that the last record has a duplicate but if I replace the `until(hasLabel('USER'))` filter by `until(bothE().count().is(0))` everything is unique. Do know why this is so? However, I will mark this as an answer now. I might need your help for one more query if I run into any issues but that will be another SO question. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: The last hop is not controlled by `repeat()` and thus has no `dedup())`. You could filter the last edges by what's already collected in `x`. That `until(bothE().count().is(0)` makes it work, sounds more like a coincidence to me.

Comment: Thank you Daniel. One final question. If I replace the `until(hasLabel('USER'))` by `until(out().count().is(0))` for the second one hop requirement, will this lead to walking the whole graph in that case?

Comment: Well, only you can know if that's a valid break condition. It will probably work in your sample graph, not sure about the full graph. Also, this condition would be very fragile, meaning your query can easily break when you change the schema.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. By any chance, did you get to see the question that I posted at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57245636/traverse-graph-database-from-random-seed-nodes ? If it is not possible to limit to number of nodes, I do not mind limiting to the number of records. Thank you.

Comment: I have now come up with a solution and need your review of that solution before I mark it as an answer. Thank you.