# Gremlin CosmosDB trying to query for a list of nodes from a list of nodes and give both back

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin, tinkerpop3

[graph image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mk3xK.png)

```
enter code here
(Query to find owner)
.inE().hasLabel('OwnedBy').outV().not(inE().hasLabel('AssignedTo').has('Status', 'InUse'))
.not(
inE()
.hasLabel('AssignedTo')
.has('Status', 'InUse')
).as('cards')

.inE()
.hasLabel('AssignedTo')
.has('Status', 'FutureUse')
.as('OwnedByRequestEdges')

.outV()
.as('OwnedByRequests')

.Select('card', 'OwnedByRequests', 'OwnedByRequestEdges', 'Owner')
```

I really want it to give me a list of the cards and the list of the requests.

I user can have multiple cards and cards can have multiple future reservations.

Comment: Pictures are nice, but could you please provide a Gremlin script that creates some sample data - here is an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51388315/gremlin-choose-one-item-at-random

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to store all the values during traversal, you should use "store" and not "as".

Since you want the "select" to run once, you need to add fold() before it.

There was a redundant "not" filter (same filter).

```
(Query to find owner)
.inE().hasLabel('OwnedBy').outV()
.not(inE().hasLabel('AssignedTo').has('Status','InUse'))
.store('Cards')
.inE().hasLabel('AssignedTo').has('Status', 'FutureUse').outV()
.store('OwnedByRequests')
.fold()
.select('Cards', 'OwnedByRequests')
```