# Tinkergraph traversal returning an empty array [] on my graph

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3, tinkergraph

I have imported a graph and can confirm that the number of vertex and edges matches the number that should be present. I run the simplepath() compute on the graph and my first question is how to access the path array or map whatever is returned, i think i understand as i add the .toList and print it to the console however i simply get [] an empty array?

What am i doing wrong i need to access the result set that comes back from the path?

my query which is run in Java not in the gramlin console is:

```
g.V().has("id", "FirstVertexIdValue").shortestPath().with(ShortestPath.target, __.has("id", "EndVertexIdValue")).with(ShortestPath.distance, "weight").toList();
```

I also run the following and still return an empty array:

```
g.V("startVertexId").out().simplePath().until(hasId("endVertexId").path().limit(1);
```

the response when systemOut printed is []

in addition the graphml doc sample is here, its a pretty big doc so i have just included 2 vertex and 2 edges:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<graphml xmlns='http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xsi:schemaLocation='http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns/1.0/graphml.xsd'>
  <key attr.name='weight' attr.type='double' for='edge' id='weight' />
  <key attr.name='edgeid' attr.type='string' for='edge' id='edgeid' />
  <key attr.name='alpha' attr.type='string' for='edge' id='alpha' />
  <key attr.name='intendedpathlonlat' attr.type='string' for='edge' id='intendedpathlonlat' />
  <key attr.name='levelid' attr.type='string' for='edge' id='levelid' />
  <key attr.name='type' attr.type='string' for='edge' id='type' />
  <key attr.name='relatedroutes' attr.type='string' for='node' id='relatedroutes' />
  <key attr.name='description' attr.type='string' for='node' id='description' />
  <key attr.name='title' attr.type='string' for='node' id='title' />
  <key attr.name='on_finish_route' attr.type='string' for='node' id='on_finish_route' />
  <key attr.name='on_starting_route' attr.type='string' for='node' id='on_starting_route' />
  <key attr.name='level_id' attr.type='string' for='node' id='level_id' />
  <key attr.name='waypoint_type' attr.type='string' for='node' id='waypoint_type' />
  <key attr.name='name' attr.type='string' for='node' id='name' />
  <key attr.name='lon' attr.type='string' for='node' id='lon' />
  <key attr.name='lat' attr.type='string' for='node' id='lat' />
  <graph edgedefault='directed' id='Station'>
    <node id='L08-022'>
      <data key='lat'>40.69330963</data>
      <data key='lon'>-73.98752537</data>
      <data key='name' />
      <data key='waypoint_type'>escalator</data>
      <data key='level_id'>1080000</data>
      <data key='on_starting_route' />
      <data key='on_finish_route' />
    </node>
    <node id='L08-023'>
      <data key='lat'>40.69318355</data>
      <data key='lon'>-73.98755793</data>
      <data key='name' />
      <data key='waypoint_type'>stairs</data>
      <data key='level_id'>1080000</data>
      <data key='on_starting_route' />
      <data key='on_finish_route' />
    </node>
    <edge source='WL10-054' target='L10-029'>
      <data key='type'>floor</data>
      <data key='weight'>4.22</data>
      <data key='levelid'>1100000</data>
      <data key='intendedpathlonlat'></data>
      <data key='alpha'>0.0</data>
      <data key='edgeid'>RL10-059</data>
    </edge>
    <edge source='WL10-054' target='WL10-053'>
      <data key='type'>floor</data>
      <data key='weight'>5.69</data>
      <data key='levelid'>1100000</data>
      <data key='intendedpathlonlat'></data>
      <data key='alpha'>0.0</data>
      <data key='edgeid'>RL10-060</data>
    </edge>
</graph>
</graphml>
```

A sample of the queries tried:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('T.id', 'L00-041').shortestPath().with(ShortestPath.target, __.has('T.id', 'L04-070')).with(ShortestPath.distance, 'weight').toList()
gremlin> g.V().has('T.id', 'L04-070').out().values('waypoint_type').fold()
==>[]
gremlin> g.V().has('T.id', 'L04-070').out().fold()
==>[]
gremlin> g.V().has('T.id', 'L04-070').out().values('lat').fold()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without some sample data it's hard to tell what might be completely wrong but here's some things to consider based on the Gremlin in your question:

- `shortestPath()`-step is a an [OLAP step](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#graphcomputer) and therefore requires that you define `g` using `withComputer()` - an example can be found [here](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#shortestpath-step).
- I notice that you search for your starting vertex in two different ways in each of your queries. In the first case you search by a property named "id" and in the second you search by the vertex identifier (referenced as `T.id` when used in `has()`). Perhaps that initial starting vertex isn't found properly?
- The second traversal looks invalid as it tries to do a loop (i.e. it has an `until()` condition) but does not specify a `repeat()` operation.

When my traversals don't return what I expect, I try to simplify them to the point where I can see where the traversal is filtering away the traversers that I expected. In other words, have Gremlin Console open and your graph connected. Ensure that `g.V("startVertexId")` returns the vertex you expect. When satisfied of the result, add a step, run `g.V("startVertexId").out()` and validate that. Continue with that pattern until you find out where your results are not returning. You can also run your traversal with `profile()` step and it should show you where the traversers are filtering away, but sometimes it's easier to recognize by picking the traversal apart and simplifying.

I tested your traversal with the data you recently supplied in your question and when I make the adjustments as suggested in my answer and comments I don't seem to have a problem getting results:

```
gremlin> g.withComputer().V('WL10-054').shortestPath().with(ShortestPath.target, __.hasId('L10-029')).with(ShortestPath.distance, 'weight')
==>[v[WL10-054],v[L10-029]]
```

Comment: @stephenMallete Thank you i can certainly share more info, However the steps you have outlined to build the traversal piece by piece make great sense so i will go away and try that initially. Thank you for your advice. Much appreciated and i will update the question when i have been through that process.

Comment: If my hints above don't lead you to an answer it would be helpful to have a small bit of sample data as a Gremlin script that can recreate the problem, as in this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51388315/gremlin-choose-one-item-at-random

Comment: I have taken steps through the gremlin console. vertex and edges are there, properties are there however if i try to run: g.V().has('T.id', 'L04-070').out().values('lat').fold() I get the [] zero array, it feels as if my edges are not connected to my vertices? my edges source and targets are the vertex id values 'L04-070' for example. how can i check its all connected?

Comment: I will add sample data now

Comment: I have a dded some extra info, my set up was: graph = TinkerGraph.open(),   g = graph.traversal(),   g = graph.traversal().withComputer()

Comment: Quick one my vertices print out as: ==>v[L08-086], where as my edges print out as: ==>e[1000][31-route->3], are they using different id's?

Comment: it's `T.id` not `"T.id"` - `T` is an enumeration - https://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/current/core/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/structure/T.html - i assume that's why you get no results. in your case though i would simple do: `g.V('L00-041')` and `hasId('L04-070')`

Comment: As for your question about the edge id not matching "edgeId" in your graphml file, I think that's because the structure of your graphml should be such that the "edgeId" be added as an attribute of the `<edge>` element as in `<edge id="RL10-059">` rather than making it a property key.

Comment: Thank you, that was spot on. The g..V('L00-041') is the way to go for me. I will query the Graphml structure and see if any changes can be made but my traversals are returning edges now. I would consider that a fix for me. Thank you so much Stephen.

Comment: Ran into another query, so i have started a new question, you may be able to help me with off the top of your head? Thanks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61177108/re-running-an-existing-route-in-a-tinkerpop-graph