# Find vertices that are related to another vertex that has duplicate properties

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3, amazon-neptune

Consider I have `person` vertices and these vertices have a `studied-at` edge to `school` vertices . If `school` vertices have a `name` property and for some reason if there are few `person` vertices that have `school` vertices with duplicate `name` property

For example a groupCount() query will give

```
g.V().hasLabel('person').out('studied-at').groupCount().by('name')
==>[s1:2]
```

Here `s1` is the name of the school , meaning person vertices have schools with duplicate school names.

How to find such `person` vertices

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.. the above query answer the question of how many persons studied at the same school by name. And does not necessarily mean that there are duplicate school names look at this simple graph: https://gremlify.com/ay

Comment: Um above query was simply for demo , it is not the exact situation 
So basically I want to find out the vertices(A) that has an edge with other vertices(B) where B vertex can have a property-value pair that repeat in other B vertices .
I want to find out all A that has the above situation

Comment: It often helps folks answer Gremlin questions if you provide a Gremlin script with some sample data along with desired output - here is an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51388315/gremlin-choose-one-item-at-random