# How to merge values from different objects in gremlin query?

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, gremlin-server, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I have a query that returns the output in the following format,

```
{
    "Key": [
      "Value1",
      "Value2"
    ],
    "Count": [
      {
        "Count1": 28,
        "Count2": 28
      },
      {
        "Count3": 16,
        "Count4": 16
      }
    ]
  }
```

I want to display it in the following format

```
[
  {
     "Key" : "Value1",
     "Count1": 28,
     "Count2": 28
  },
  {
     "Key" : "Value2",
     "Count3": 16,
     "Count4": 16
  }
]
```

Is it possible?

The gremlin that produces a similar output

```
g.V().
has('organizationId', 'b121672e-8049-40cc-9f28-c62dff4cc2d9').
hasLabel('employee').

group(). 
by('officeId').
by(project('Id', 'Status').
    by(choose(has('officeId'), constant('Total'), constant(''))).
    by(coalesce(out('hasStatus').
                or(
                        has('release', is(false)),                          
                        has('autoRelease', is(true)).
                        has('release', is(true)).
                        has('endDate', gte(637250976000000000))
                 ), values('status'), constant('Green'))).
    select(values).
    unfold().
    groupCount()).

    project('Id', 'Count').
    by(select(keys)).
    by(select(values))
```

And the data that I have is an *employee* vertex and a *healthStatus* vertex, there's an *hasStatus* edge between employee and healthStatus

**Properties in employee vertex:**
id, organizations, officeId, Name, createdOn

**Properties in healthStatus vertex:**
id, status, startDate, endDate, release, autoRelease, createdOn

Sample Data

```
 g.addV('employee').
       property('id',1).
       property('organizationId',1).
       property('officeId',1).
       property('name','A').
       property('createdOn', 637263231140000000).as('1').
    addV('employee').
       property('id',2).
       property('organizationId',1).
       property('officeId',2).
       property('name','B').
       property('createdOn', 637263231140000000).as('2').
   addV('employee').
       property('id',5).
       property('organizationId',1).
       property('officeId',3).
       property('name','C').
       property('createdOn', 637263231140000000).as('5').
    addV('healthStatus').
       property('id',3).
       property('status','Red').
       property('startDate',637262367140000000).
       property('endDate',637264095140000000).
       property('release',false).
       property('createdOn',637262367140000000)as('3').
    addV('healthStatus').
       property('id',4).
       property('status','Yellow').
       property('startDate',637262367140000000).
       property('endDate',637264095140000000).
       property('release',false).
       property('createdOn',637262367140000000)as('4').
    addE('hasStatus').from('1').to('3').
    addE('hasStatus').from('4').to('4')
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "Id" : [
        1,
        2,
        3
      ]
  },
  {
    "Count": [
      {
         "Red" : 1
      },
      {
         "Yellow" : 1
      },
      {
         "Green" : 1
      }
    ]  
  }
```

Expected Output

```
[
  {
     "Id" : 1,
     "Red" : 1
  },
  {
     "Id" : 2,
     "Yellow" : 1
  },
  {
     "Id" : 3,
     "Green" : 1
  }
]
```

**Note** : This Id in projection is officeId from employee vertex

Comment: While it may be possible to get this data to a form that you want, I often find that if my Gremlin is devolving into a lot of intense data transformation code it's possible that I've structured the rest of my query in a way that has put me in that place and that I need to re-think that part of the query. Would you care to share the Gremlin that produces this output (and some sample data - example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51388315/gremlin-choose-one-item-at-random) so that I can see if there is a way to restructure that part to get the result you want?

Comment: @stephenmallette I have added the query

Comment: Your description of the data/schema is nice, but an actual script that could be executed to generate the data would be better. perhaps you could simplify the filtering as well, since that isn't core to your question which would make the example data script even easier to put together and the query itself more focused on the problem. As it sits, I'm not sure your traversal even executes - do you mind reviewing it please to be sure you pasted the right code in there? maybe i'm missing something but the parenthesis don't seem to line up in a way i'd expect and `coalesce()` only has one argument.

Comment: @stephenmallette I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've captured what you wanted. There were some errors in your sample data script and I wanted some extra data to make sure counts were making sense so I added a bit:

```
 g = TinkerGraph.open().traversal()
 g.addV('employee').
       property('id',1).
       property('organizationId',1).
       property('officeId',1).
       property('name','A').
       property('createdOn', 637263231140000000).as('1').
    addV('employee').
       property('id',2).
       property('organizationId',1).
       property('officeId',2).
       property('name','B').
       property('createdOn', 637263231140000000).as('2').
   addV('employee').
       property('id',5).
       property('organizationId',1).
       property('officeId',3).
       property('name','C').
       property('createdOn', 637263231140000000).as('5').
   addV('employee').
       property('id',6).
       property('organizationId',1).
       property('officeId',3).
       property('name','D').
       property('createdOn', 637263231140000000).as('6').
    addV('healthStatus').
       property('id',3).
       property('status','Red').
       property('startDate',637262367140000000).
       property('endDate',637264095140000000).
       property('release',false).
       property('createdOn',637262367140000000).as('3').
    addV('healthStatus').
       property('id',4).
       property('status','Yellow').
       property('startDate',637262367140000000).
       property('endDate',637264095140000000).
       property('release',false).
       property('createdOn',637262367140000000).as('4').
    addE('hasStatus').from('1').to('3').
    addE('hasStatus').from('2').to('4').
    addE('hasStatus').from('6').to('4')
```

I've re-written you traversal a bit to provide a different approach that I think provides the data you expect, however in a slightly different form:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('employee','organizationId', 1).
......1>   project('Id', 'Status').
......2>     by('officeId').
......3>     by(coalesce(out('hasStatus').
......4>                 or(has('release', false),                          
......5>                    has('autoRelease', true).has('release', true).has('endDate', gte(637250976000000000))). 
......6>                 values('status'), 
......7>                 constant('Green'))).
......8>   group().
......9>     by(select('Id')).
.....10>     by(groupCount().
.....11>          by('Status'))
==>[1:[Red:1],2:[Yellow:1],3:[Yellow:1,Green:1]]
```

I prefer this form a bit, but perhaps you require the original format you inquired about, in which case you need another round of manipulation on the collection:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('employee','organizationId', 1).
......1>   project('Id', 'Status').
......2>     by('officeId').
......3>     by(coalesce(out('hasStatus').
......4>                 or(has('release', false),                          
......5>                    has('autoRelease', true).has('release', true).has('endDate', gte(637250976000000000))). 
......6>                 values('status'), 
......7>                 constant('Green'))).
......8>   group().
......9>     by(select('Id')).
.....10>     by(groupCount().
.....11>          by('Status')).
.....12>   unfold().
.....13>   map(union(project('Id').by(select(keys)),
.....14>             select(values)).
.....15>       unfold().
.....16>       group().by(keys).by(select(values)))
==>[Red:1,Id:1]
==>[Yellow:1,Id:2]
==>[Yellow:1,Id:3,Green:1]
```