# Gremlin - Ordered list of vertexes, with soonest related vertex

Tags: gremlin

First off, I'm new to Gremlin, so any advice would be hugely appreciated!

I'm trying to get an alphabetically ordered list of people, alongside their soonest session by start date. My graph looks like this -

person.1[V] - has_session[E] -> session.1[V]

person.1[V] - has_session[E] -> session.2[V]

person.2[V] - has_session[E] -> session.3[V]

person.2[V] - has_session[E] -> session.4[V]

Person vertexes have a name attribute, and session vertexes have a start time attribute with a unix timestamp.

I'd like to return all the attributes for both the person and the session, such as with elementMap().

I can't seem to work out how to maintain the two sorts, name of person, and start of session, and apply the limits to only one part.

```
g.V().hasLabel('person').
  order().by('name').
    as('person').
  out('has_session').has('start', gte(1595805580)).
    as('sessions').
  dedup('person').path().
  select('person', 'sessions').
    by(elementMap())
```

Comment: Could you please provide a Gremlin script that creates some sample data - here is an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51388315/gremlin-choose-one-item-at-random

Answer (score 1):

I think this is doing the job -

```
g.V().hasLabel('person').
  order().
    by('name', asc).
  filter(out('session').has('start', gte(1595805580))).
  project('person', 'next_session').
    by(elementMap()).
    by(out('session').has('status', 'available')
      order().by('start').
      elementMap().limit(1).fold())
```