# gremlin - how to multiply "carried" properties

Tags: javascript, gremlin, amazon-neptune

Given the following  graph:

- vertices of type "Companies" holding a "name" property
- edges  of type "Shareholder"  holding a "holding" property .

Definition:

- Beneficiary : Company with **direct or indirect** holding in the company

Graph example :

-CompanyB holds 0.5 of companyC - CompanyA holds 0.5 companyB  . Both companies are considered companyC's beneficiaries (each hold  0.5 directly and 0.25 indirectly respectively

[image: Graph example]

Creating example:

```
// create an empty graph
graph = TinkerFactory.createModern()
g = graph.traversal()
g.V().drop()

// create data
companyA =  g.addV('Company').property('name', 'A').next()
companyB= g.addV('Company').property('name', 'B').next()
companyC = g.addV('Company').property('name', 'C').next()
g.addE("Shareholder").from(companyB)
 .to(companyC).property("holding",0.5)
g.addE("Shareholder").from(companyA)
 .to(companyB).property("holding", 0.5)
```

Desired Solution:

- I want to calculate CompanyC's beneficiaries and their holdings in the Company.
- I'm only interesting in two levels deep (e.g I don't care companyA's shareholders )
- I do want to preserve the holding hierarchy .

Solution Example :

```
[{

   name:"B",

   holding:0.5,

   shareholders:[
         {
           name:"A",
           holding:0.25
           }
       ]}
    ] 


}]
```

My Attempt :

```
   // js
   let companyCBeneficiaries  =await  g.V(companyC.id)
   .inE()
   .project( 
      "holding",
       "name",
       "shareholders"
   )
   .by(__.identity().values("holding"))
   .by(__.coalesce(__.outV().values("name") , __.constant("")))
   .by(
       __.coalesce(
             __.outV().inE().project(
                 "name",
                 "holding"
             )
                 .by(__.coalesce(__.outV().values("name") , __.constant("")))
                 .by(__.identity().values("holding"))
             ,
            __.constant([])
       )
   )

   .toList()

 // console

 g.V(companyC).inE().project("holding","name","shareholders")
 .by(__.identity().values("holding"))
  .by(__.coalesce(__.outV().values("name") ,__.constant(""))) 
  .by(__.coalesce(__.outV().inE().project("name","holding")
            .by(__.coalesce(__.outV().values("name") , 
               __.constant("")))
           .by(__.identity().values("holding")) 
                   ,__.constant([]))).toList()
```

Which result in CompanyA.holding = 0.5 instead of 0.25 (currently Im iterating  over companyCBeneficiaries fixing the holding property  )

Comment: The picture is nice but could you please provide a Gremlin script that creates some sample data - here is an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51388315/gremlin-choose-one-item-at-random - that way you can get a fully tested traversal as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made your sample data bit more robust:

```
g = TinkerGraph.open().traversal()
companyA = g.addV('Company').property('name', 'A').next()
companyB = g.addV('Company').property('name', 'B').next()
companyC = g.addV('Company').property('name', 'C').next()
companyD = g.addV('Company').property('name', 'D').next()
companyE = g.addV('Company').property('name', 'E').next()
g.addE("Shareholder").from(companyB).to(companyC).property("holding",0.5)
g.addE("Shareholder").from(companyA).to(companyB).property("holding", 0.5)
g.addE("Shareholder").from(companyD).to(companyC).property("holding", 0.5)
g.addE("Shareholder").from(companyE).to(companyB).property("holding", 0.5)
```

and used `sack()` which I think gets you what you are after:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('Company','name','C').
......1>   inE('Shareholder').
......2>   sack(assign).by('holding').
......3>   project('name','holding','shareholders').
......4>     by(outV().values('name')).
......5>     by(sack()).
......6>     by(outV().
......7>        inE('Shareholder').
......8>        sack(mult).by('holding').
......9>        project('name','holding').
.....10>          by(outV().values('name')).
.....11>          by(sack()).
.....12>        fold())
==>[name:B,holding:0.5,shareholders:[[name:A,holding:0.25],[name:E,holding:0.25]]]
==>[name:D,holding:0.5,shareholders:[]]
```