# Gremlin Python: Response of queries are different

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, gremlinpython

I think i made a mistake such a duplicate the vertices.

I have two query and responses are different.

```
from gremlin_python.process.traversal import P
    
d_o_c = graph.V().has("cid", "value", '123124').in_('o_f_d').values().toList()
c_o_d = graph.V().has("did", "value", P.within(d_o_c)).out('o_f_d').values().toList()
print(c_o_d)
```

The response of above query is:

```
[[1231245, 123124]]
```

Query of the above is not fast at all.

So I changed my query like that:

```
c_o_d = graph.V().has("cid", "value", '123124').in_('o_f_d').out('o_f_d').values().toList()
print(c_o_d)
```

The response of the query is:

```
[123124]
```

Also I want to see the path of the query:

```
c_o_d = graph.V().has("client_id", "value", '123124').in_('o_f_d').out('o_f_d').path().by('value').toList()
```

Response of the query is:

```
[path[123124, 34335-324434-23-4-5445, 123124]]
```

The other cid is not coming out with above query. Is there a another way to get the result like first query else than the drop duplicates and adding edges between vertices?

My graph is:

```
'cid-a' <---o_f_d---- 'did' ---o_f_d---> 'cid-b'
```

I need the get all 'cid' values from cid-a

Comment: not sure if you're still having this problem but perhaps a fully failing example with sample data would help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51388315/gremlin-choose-one-item-at-random

Comment: thank you @stephenmallette . i solved issue with adding edges between existing nodes again. when i add edge between existing nodes this query returns correctly. should i clear question with sample data and response to the question with that way?

Comment: It's OK to answer your own question also if that may help others that find the question.