# Travers to vertex with multiple incoming edges

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I am running cosmosdb with the Gremlin API, giving me a graph database.  Most of my gremlin traversals are basic stuff, but I have one that I can't figure out the query for.  Take this model

[image]

I want to start at Service B.  I want to walk `outE("MAKES_CONNECTION")` edges to only `ServiceConnections` that have an `inE("CONNECTION_ENVIRONMENT")` where the properties of the environment are `stage=dev` and `env=dev`.  Then step down the `ServiceConnection.outE("MAKES_CONNECTION")` and print off the `ServiceName` value, in this case, the printed value would be `Service C`

To explain whats going on here in plain text.  `Service B` makes an HTTP connection to `Service C` in the Dev environment.  But in the QA environment, it makes a connection to `Service D`

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but I think this is right (pictures are nice, but if you want a tested traversal it's always best to [include some sample data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51388315/gremlin-choose-one-item-at-random)):

```
g.V().has('ServiceMap','ServiceName','B').
  out('MAKES_CONNECTION').has('type','ServiceConnection').
  filter(__.in('CONNECTION_ENVIRONMENT').has('stage','dev').has('env','dev')).
  values('ServiceName')
```